# Delete files older than 30 days under S3 bucket recursively without deleting folders using PowerShell

Tags: amazon-web-services, powershell, amazon-s3

I can delete files and exclude folders with following script

```
aws s3 rm s3://my-bucket/ --recursive --exclude="*" --include="*/*.*"
```

when i tried to add pipe to delete only older files, i'm unable to.. please help with the script.

```
aws s3 rm s3://my-bucket/ --recursive --exclude="*" --include="*/*.*" | Where-Object {($_.LastModified -lt (Get-Date).AddDays(-31))}
```

Comment: When you say "without deleting folders", how were these folders created?

Comment: Created manually by clicking on New Folder option

Comment: In that case, when deleting objects you would need to avoid deleting any zero-length objects, since they are created when the "Create folder" button is used.

Comment: I can able to avoid deleting folders, please review my PowerShell code once.. i want to delete older files only

Comment: This is different question then 63991288(for Python), current question (64020684) is for PowerShell

Answer (score 0):

The approach should be to `list` the files you need, then pipe the results to a `delete` call (a reverse of what you have). This might be better managed by a full blown script rather than a one line shell command. There's an article on this and some examples [here](https://www.thetopsites.net/article/53041990.shtml).

Going forward, you should let [S3 versioning](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/Versioning.html) take care of this, then you don't have to manage a script or remember to run it. Note: it'll only work with files that are added after versioning has been enabled.